# howto resolve this string with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have a problem, i'm working with jquery and some ajax requests.

i'm getting a string like: `5 12 6 8`

now i want to split this string into `5,12,6,8` and then add the numbers to some elements like:

```
$("#l1").html("5");
$("#l2").html("12");
$("#l3").html("6");
$("#l4").html("8");
```

the problem is, that there are not always 4 numbers, sometimes 8, other times just one. when there is just one it would be:

```
$("#l1").html("x");
```

x should be the number which i get.

how to resolve this with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `str` is a string that looks like "5 12 6 8":

```
$.each(str.split(' '), function(i, val) {
    $('#l'+(i+1)).html(val);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sxucs/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function like this:

```
var input = "1 2 3 4 5";
var splitted = input.split(' ');
$.each(splitted, function(index, value) {
    $("#l" + value).html(value);
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qW7LU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

even better is it to provide your data as [JSON-Object](http://www.json.org) ! Set the data-type of your jquery-ajax request to json (or let it guess) and you can retrieve the values like from an ordinary js-object.